# How to ignore Unicode whitespace characters encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a csv file with the following information:

```
id  name    age     height  weight
1   x       12      11      124
2   y       13      23      432
3   z       14      43      1435
```

It's stored in a file called Workbook2.csv
I use the following code:

```
ipFile = csv.DictReader(open('Workbook2.csv', 'rU'))
dict = {} # Tring to update the rows to this dictionary.
for row in ipFile:
    print row
```

I get the following result:

```
{'weight': '124', '\xef\xbb\xbfid': '1', 'height ': '11', 'age   ': '12', 'name ': 'x'}
{'weight': '432', '\xef\xbb\xbfid': '2', 'height ': '23', 'age   ': '13', 'name ': 'y'}
{'weight': '1435', '\xef\xbb\xbfid': '3', 'height ': '43', 'age   ': '14', 'name ': 'z'}
```

I would like to know how I can update this output to a dictionary.
I would also like to know how I can ignore the unicode characters that are encoded usig UTF-8, if there is a filter I can use to eliminate them.

Comment: Presumably this is Python 2?

Comment: looks like some BOM header

Comment: Your lines have a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) prefixed. On every single line. How was the data produced in the first place?

Comment: This right here is in Python2, but I will have to right it in Python3 as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes this was the way the data was produced.

Comment: That wasn't the question. Your data is broken. Fix the producer, not the consumer.

Comment: @TheTank: I realise that this is the way the data is produced. Much more important: can you fix the way the data is produced?

Answer (score 2):

Your input data contains [UTF-8 BOM sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) on *every single line*. Whatever produced this file seemed to have been appending data one line at a time using the `utf-8-sig` codec or the non-Python equivalent. The BOM (if used at all) should be the first character in the file and *not used anywhere else*. Your data is broken, if you can possibly fix this at the source, do so.

However, there is a way to repair this as you read. The 'file' that is read by the `csv` module can be anything that produces lines as you iterate. Use a generator to filter the file lines first:

```
from codecs import BOM_UTF8

def bom_filter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(BOM_UTF8):
            line = line[len(BOM_UTF8):]
        yield line
```

then pass your file through the filter before passing it to the `DictReader()` object:

```
with open('Workbook2.csv', 'rU') as inputfile:
    ipFile = csv.DictReader(bom_filter(inputfile))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> import csv
>>> from codecs import BOM_UTF8
>>> def bom_filter(lines):
...     for line in lines:
...         if line.startswith(BOM_UTF8):
...             line = line[len(BOM_UTF8):]
...         yield line
...
>>> demofile = BytesIO('''\
... \xef\xbb\xbfid,name,age,height,weight
... \xef\xbb\xbf1,x,12,11,124
... \xef\xbb\xbf2,y,13,23,432
... \xef\xbb\xbf3,z,14,43,1435
... ''')
>>> ipFile = csv.DictReader(bom_filter(demofile))
>>> for row in ipFile:
...     print row
...
{'age': '12', 'height': '11', 'id': '1', 'weight': '124', 'name': 'x'}
{'age': '13', 'height': '23', 'id': '2', 'weight': '432', 'name': 'y'}
{'age': '14', 'height': '43', 'id': '3', 'weight': '1435', 'name': 'z'}
```

In Python 3, the `csv` module takes Unicode string input (as opposed to bytestrings, so now you need to look for the decoded result, the U+FEFF zero-width space codepoint. To make the code work on either Python version, you'd have to swap out what you are testing for at the start of the line:

```
import sys
to_filter = u'\ufeff'
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    to_filter = to_filter.encode('utf8')

def bom_filter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(to_filter):
            line = line[len(to_filter):]
        yield line
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It solved the BOM issue. But I'm still getting \xc2\xc0 in other dataset. Can you giude me as to to ignore these invisible whitespaces and such?

Comment: @TheTank: that's an incomplete UTF-8 byte sequence, so I can't really comment on what that sequence means and how to handle it.

Comment: @TheTank: you have UTF-8 data, so there could well be non-ASCII data in that stream that is not whitespace. But I can't tell that from an incomplete byte sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There is a kwarg skipinitialspace but I verified from the C code that it only looks for ' '.

Two possibilities:

1. Subclass DictReader to add some code to strip out the spaces
2. Massage the lines from your file before passing them into the DictReader.

An example of (2) would be:

```
import io
with io.open('Workbook2.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
    ipFile = csv.DictReader((x.replace(u"\uFEFF", u" ") for x in infile))
....
```

Comment: There is no need to read everything into several lists first. Use a generator expression, like `(x.replace(u"\uFEFF", u"") for x in infile)`. Not that the lines are Unicode strings, so your replacements will fail.

Comment: Edited to ensure we get Unicode strings from UTF8-encoded file. Did not have ttime to verify that CSV DictReader copes with Unicode strings.

Comment: But the `csv.DictReader()` **can't handle Unicode inputs**.

Comment: And you are still reading the whole file into memory as one big list, then producing a new list with the zero-width non-breaking space characters removed, and only then passing that to the reader. There is no need to waste all this memory.

Comment: You are still reading in the whole file with `infile.readlines()`. And you are still expecting the Python 2 `csv` module to handle Unicode strings. That only works (by accident) if the data is ASCII-clean.

Comment: Edited to use inherent iterator from file. Yes, this example won't work for Python 3. Your sample code on this response is certainly more general.

Comment: No, the example won't work on *Python 2*, if the input file has UTF-8 data outside the ASCII range.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the output is clearly misinterpreted.

DictReader takes the fieldnames from the first line and the first column (that one after the invisible BOM) is just "id". That is why the id field now has the BOM prepended in every record.

In python 2.7 and 3.6, I had to use the dialect `csv.excel_tab` to enable interpretation of the tabs as delimiters.

Your input data/csv file is absolutely ok, as there is just a BOM at the beginning (where it should be). You just need to strip the BOM before reading.

E.g. like this:

```
from codecs import BOM_UTF8
csv_file = open('test2.csv', 'rU')
csv_file.seek(len(BOM_UTF8))
ipFile = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```